# Puppeteer won't start cpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, cpanel, html-pdf

I am trying to run puppeteer on a cpanel server but it won't start up, it works fine on my pc and on heroku though.

The error i keep getting says a dependency is missing, I would know how to solve it if it was on my pc, but i can't install dependencies on the cpanel server. The nodejs version i'm working with on the server is 14.20.0

The error i keep getting is:

```
Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/oyaaducr/nodevenv/api/14/lib/node_modules/puppeteer-core/.local-chromium/linux-1045629/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: install the missing dependencies, google the error for further info / dupes, or go to https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1598

Comment: Was there any effort made to troubleshoot or research this issue before posting to SO? What steps have you taken to solve the issue yourself? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Lawrence Cherone, Like i said in the initial post, i can't install dependencies on the cpanel server, I have tried using several linux package managers and non of them work. I even looked through the "bin" folder in root directory and there doesn't seem to be any package managers installed, if you know how i can get around this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You just needs to upload the local `package.json` to Application root then `Run NPM Install` to install missing dependencies

[image]

Comment: the missing dependency i suspect is a sub-dependency(a dependency of a dependency), so copying over the "package.json" won't help